# Intento aceder a la carpeta Storage Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola amigos intento visualizar un archivo PDF en laravel mi dirección es está `storage/app/public/cv` no me deja visualizar el PDF

UneteController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->nombre !="" && $request->apellidos != "" && $request->telefono != "" && $request->email != "" && $request->cv != ""){
            if($request->cv->getClientOriginalExtension() == "pdf")
            {
                $path = $request->file('cv')->store('public/storage/unete/cv');
                $path = str_replace("public","public",$path);
                $solicitudes = new SolicitudesTable();
                $solicitudes->tipo = $request->tipo;
                $solicitudes->nombre = $request->nombre;
                $solicitudes->apellidos = $request->apellidos;
                $solicitudes->telefono = $request->telefono;
                $solicitudes->email = $request->email;
                $solicitudes->grado_academico = $request->grado_academico;
                $solicitudes->comentarios = $request->comentarios;
                $solicitudes->cv = $path;
                $solicitudes->save();
                return back()->with('correcto',"Guardado");

            }else {
                return back()->with('error',"Formato de archivo incorrecto");
            }
        }else{
            return back()->with('camposvacios',"Falta completar algunos datos");
        }
    }
```

Solicitudes.blade.php

```
<tbody>
         @for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($promotor); $i++)
                      <tr>
      <td>{{$promotor[$i]->nombre}} {{ $promotor[$i]->apellidos}}</td>
                            <td>{{$promotor[$i]->telefono}}</td>
                            <td>{{$promotor[$i]->email}}</td>
                            <td>{{$promotor[$i]->grado_academico}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <a href="{{url('storage/'.$promotor[$i]->cv)}}" target="_blank">
                                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{$promotor[$i]->comentarios}}</td>
                            <th scope="row"><a class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" href="#" onclick="borrar({{$promotor[$i]->id}})"></a></th>
                          </tr>
                        @endfor
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Creaste le enlace simbólico?

Comment: Cual es el enlace simbolico?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Ya lo intente hacer pero me dice que ya existe

Comment: Mi duda si estoy bien haciendo esto $path = $request->file('cv')->store('public/storage/unete/cv');

Comment: TEngo el mismo problema, lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar storeAs en su lugar:

```
$file = $request->file('cv');
$path = $file->storeAs(
    'unete', 'cv.' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->extension(), 'public'
);
```

Si necesitas más info, en la documentación de Laravel encuentras más opciones: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#files

Comment: Ya implemente tu código pero sigue sin visualizar url es https://tdrivers.com.mx/Unete/public/unete/cvCV-Eduardo%20Fuentes.pdf

Comment: @Nicolás si no funciona el código, ¿para qué aceptaste la respuesta?

Comment: Shaz en una parte si sirve pero estoy hablando con la chica gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿puede que sea el virtualhost que sobreescribe el acceso a storage? Si subió el archivo, debería ser accesible directamente.